# Animation after clicking on View

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, ripple

[image]

How to create this kind of ripple effect in swift after clicking on View
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

check it https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/piripple and https://github.com/manekdilip/MTRipple for ripple effect in swift... Both are swift project...i think that 2 project is help for you for ripple effect on UIView...If Any problem then reply me....